# Visa Application Question

Tags: visas, schengen, nigerian-citizens

I am a Nigerian, applying for a Schengen Visa to Italy, and while filling out the form, encountered this question: a. Member State(s) of destination. b. Member state of first entry. Please, what do I fill in there?

Comment: Why have you used Alphas in places of As?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a) you put the Schengen state that you are primarily visiting - in general, this is the country you will spend the most time in, although this can get a bit murkier if your main purpose of travel is a particular event, but that you will spend more or equal time in another country.
For b) you need to put down the first Schegen country you will be arriving in. So whichever member of the Schengen area your plane or boat from Nigeria first arrives in.